# Get snapshots after upgrade Elasticsearch 2.4 to 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, snapshot

I made the upgrade in my elasticsearch cluster 2.4 version to 5.6. (as described in elastic website). The upgrade occurred without issues, but now I needed check the snapshots available and receive the error:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_logs/_all?pretty"

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "repository_exception",
        "reason" : "[es_logs] could not read repository data from index blob"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[es_logs] could not read repository data from index blob",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "access_denied_exception",
      "reason" : "/mnt/backup/elasticsearch/es_logs/pending-incompatible-snapshots-uMo3FaYxST6JFL_t8LOv8w"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I appreciate any suggestion or feedback to resolve my problem. Thank all.

**UPDATE**: In other cluster, I considered the same process  for upgrade and not have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me before when upgraded from es v5.x to es v6.x.
Caused by data corruption in the data segments of the snapshots.

How a snapshot works behind the scenes is: from the 2nd snapshot and on, on a certain cluster, the new snapshot relays on older data segments that already got snapshotted before (in previous snapshots you've done)
so the current snapshot wouldn't have to begin from scratch, this is a smart way of ES to gain efficiency. that is also why the first snapshot takes longer.

Please read more about it in the ES documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-snapshot-and-restore).

For me, it helped to delete all of my snapshots, therefore to delete all the old data segments, then do another snapshot. Like a fresh start.

If that doesn't help I would suggest doing a rolling restart to your cluster
then delete all the old snapshots and then do a new one

Read about rolling restart [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-cluster.html).

Also, I would suggest reviewing your es repositories paths, definitions, and configurations. might be that the upgrade caused some faults.

Hope it would help and gl.

Overall v5.6 has some known issues regarding snapshot and restore api that got fixed in v6.x, so if possible I would recommend upgrading to 6.x.

Comment: Thanks Yotam. I need recovery the data. For that, I performed the downgrade of elasticsearch to 2.4.